# Difference between openssl s_client invocation in cron and in a terminal

Tags: terminal, cron, openssl

I'd like to monitor Microsoft Exchange banners.

When in console I run command:

```
timeout 1 openssl s_client -connect 192.168.0.5:995 > /tmp/1.txt
```

Output:

```
tail -n 4 /tmp/1.txt: 
    Timeout   : 300 (sec) 
    Verify return code: 0 (ok) 
--- 
+OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
```

When I add this command to cron, I get this output

```
tail -n 4 /tmp/1.txt 
        Start Time: 1488382801 
        Timeout   : 300 (sec) 
        Verify return code: 0 (ok) 
---
```

What the difference between cron and console? Thank you.

Comment: This may be dependent on whether or not your process has a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, when running under `cron`, the connection was closed before the remote server had a chance to issue its banner. This is because `openssl s_client` operates a bidirectional connection between its stdio and the socket to the remote server:

- It copies stdin to the socket
- It copies data received on the socket to stdout

When running under `cron`, the first copy terminates immediately, because stdin is connected to `/dev/null`. This caused `openssl` to quit right away.

You could mitigate this by redirecting `openssl`'s input to something that blocks forever, or better yet, something like `sleep 1` which will obviate the need for `timeout`.

Still, waiting one second is a particularly fragile way to connect and wait for a banner. Not only is it quite a short timeout, but it doesn't even cause the command to exit ahead of the timeout's expiration when the banner is received. For something like this, you are looking for `expect`.

---

By the way:

Others will probably disagree, but I believe your usage of the term "console" in this question is inexact. Actually, you would get the behaviour you first describe in *any* terminal session, which could be, among other things,:

- an ssh terminal session,
- a terminal emulator (like `xterm` or the modern replacements) in your GUI
- a `screen` window,
- a serial modem connection,
- or the actual system console.

I believe the term "console" should refer exclusively to the last one, yet all of these are terminal sessions.

Answer (score -1):

Cron use a minimal set of environment variables to your jobs. And may use other functions than you use in the console.

You can use `which <programname>` command to see the location of timeout and openssl when you use them in console and also in cron.

You can also set the `PATH` variable at the start of your script.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't help